# Allow hyphenation in custom latex bib style

Tags: hyphenation, doi, custom-bib

I created a custom bib style which renders a reference as

```
[14] R. Boer.
     Vektor- und Tensorrechnung fur Ingenieure.
     Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg, 1st ed., 1982.
     doi:10.1007/978-3-642-81901-8.
```

How can I allow the cutting of entries so that I get everything on the same line

```
[14] R. Boer., Vektor- und Tensorrechnung fur Ingenieure, Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg, 1st ed., 1982, doi:10.1007/978-3-642-81901-8.
```

which would eventually be adapted to the size of the document as

```
[14] R. Boer., Vektor- und Tensorrechnung fur
     Ingenieure, Springer-Verlag Berlin Heide
     -lberg, 1st ed., 1982, doi:10.1007/978-3
     -642-81901-8.
```

with a working url redirection for the doi.

thanks !

edit: I just figured out it is called hyphenation

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by disabling "openbib" document option.